# Is there a way to refer to an operator as a two-argument closure?

Tags: groovy, closures, operators

Sometimes I need to pass an operator as a closure, like this:

```
do.some.thing() { x,y -> x+y }
```

I'm wondering if there is any shorthand "operator pointer" syntax, analogous to the ["method pointer" syntax](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#method-pointer-operator), that would give me the operator already wrapped into a two-argument closure.

I see that most arithmetic operators are available as methods on Number and related classes:

```
public Number plus(Number right)

Add two numbers and return the result.
```

but they are instance methods and I can't figure out if I can use the [method pointer operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#method-pointer-operator) `.&` to turn them into a two-argument closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no such operator.

The method pointer operator won't work because the `MethodClosure` it creates basically has an object, in this case the `Number` class, and a method *name*. So if you do...

```
def c = Number.&plus
```

Then calling `c` will attempt to call `plus()` on the `Number` *class*, which of course won't work.

The only shortcut I can think of is to declare your operator closures once and simply reuse them as needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this sort of thing as well...

Not sure `uncurry` is the right term, but it's almost right ;-)

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure

def uncurry(MethodClosure c) {
    {a, ...b -> a."$c.method"(*b) }
}
```

Then, to make a 2 arg closure from `Number.plus`, you can do:

```
def plus = uncurry(Number.&plus)
```

And then:

```
assert plus(1, 2) == 3
```

Which also works with other method handles as well:

```
def collate = uncurry(List.&collate)
assert collate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, true) == [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

Comment: NB:  `uncurry` definitely isn't the right term to use here...not sure it has a name